# Can googletest stringification produce a hexadecimal format?

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm using Google Test to assert that certain error codes occur, and these are always hex constants. So this output is less than ideal:

mytest.cpp line 130 and its output:

```
EXPECT_EQ(0xBFFF0011, error)  << "Expected second close to return an error";

[ RUN      ] MyTest.CloseSessionFail
mytest.cpp(130): error: Value of: error
  Actual: -1074130544
Expected: 0xBFFF0011
Which is: 3221159953
Expected second close to return an error
```

For EXPECT_EQ(expected, actual), is there some way to cause it to format hexadecimal output?

Ideally I'd like to see this:

```
  Actual: 0xBFFA1190
Expected: 0xBFFF0011
```

Comment: The preprocessor isn't involved with that number formatting.

Comment: If you want custom formatting you should use a [Predicate Formatter](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Using_a_Predicate-Formatter).

Comment: @IInspectable: thanks, that was the hint I needed. I first made a class to wrap the error type, with an output operator that does hex.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this message will help you:
https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/222